# Copying arrays - does the initial size even matter?

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm new to Java so this question may look a little silly, probably, but anyway... Suppose we have a code like this:

```
int[] oneArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int[] anotherOne = new int[150];
anotherOne = Arrays.copyOf(oneArray, oneArray.length);
```

When I print the anotherOne, no matter what the initial size was, after the copyOf method it will be what we stated as the second parameter of the said function. In the case above, the array will shrink to 10 elements (or the pointer will start pointing to another place in the memory, where a new, 10-element array was created, I suppose?). So do I get it wrong or the initial size of anotherOne has no significance at all and if it's created to just become a copy at some point in the future, it should rather be initialized without specifying the size (int[] anotherOne;)?

Comment: If you want `int[150]` just do `Arrays.copyOf(oneArray, 150);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this, instead. This will save you from creating an unneeded intermediary array.

```
int[] oneArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int[] anotherOne = Arrays.copyOf(oneArray, oneArray.length);
```

If, however, you really need your second array to be of length `150`, then you can write this:

```
int[] oneArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int[] anotherOne = new int[150];
System.arraycopy(oneArray, 0, anotherOne, 0, oneArray.length);
```

Answer (score 6):

`Arrays.copyOf` already makes a copy. You don't need to initialize `anotherOne` before that:

```
int[] oneArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int[] anotherOne = Arrays.copyOf(oneArray, oneArray.length);
```

What happens with your code is that

- `oneArray` creates an array in memory
- `anotherOne` creates an array of 150 integer in memory
- the `Arrays.copyOf` method creates a third array, and makes the variable `anotherOne` point to this array. The result of this is that there is no more reference to your array of 150 elements, so it will be garbage collected.

That means, in practice, your code will work perfectly, but you are using CPU time (and memory for a short time) for creating and erasing an array of 150 integers for nothing.

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.copyOf` is returning a new array that has been created within that method. You assign that new array to the variable `anotherOne`, losing the reference to the array that you've created, which will then be eligible for garbage collection.

So the size that you use to create an array with `int[] anotherOne = new int[150];` *doesn't* matter, nor does your initialization or the array that you create with it.

You might as well use:

```
int[] anotherOne = Arrays.copyOf(oneArray, oneArray.length);
```

Or:

```
int[] anotherOne;

// ...
anotherOne = Arrays.copyOf(oneArray, oneArray.length);
```

If you really need the result to have at least *150* elements, you can also make that happen with `Array.copyOf`:

```
int[] anotherOne =
    Arrays.copyOf(oneArray, (oneArray.length > 150) ? oneArray.length() : 150);
```

Now `anotherOne` will have at least *150* elements.

Answer (score 1):

No.

When you do something like

```
int[] one = initilize...
int[] two = initilize...
two = one;
```

The initial value of one is handled by `Garbage Collector`